# Conectar a webSocket

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de conectarme a el backend mediante websockets. La idea es enviar mensajes del server a el app(Push Notifications). Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 var cliente = new ClientWebSocket();

            WebSocketReceiveResult result;

            ArraySegment<byte> segmento = new ArraySegment<byte>();

            await cliente.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://10.0.2.2:5000/ws"), CancellationToken.None);

            await Task.Run(async()=> {

                while (true)
                {

                  result= await cliente.ReceiveAsync(segmento, CancellationToken.None);

                    var messageBytes = segmento.Skip(segmento.Offset).Take(result.Count).ToArray();

                    string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);

                }

            });
```

Pero al momento de conectar , es decir en el método cliente.ConnectAsync() me envia el siguiente error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer.Array'
```

Que es lo que me hace falta?

Comment: Porqué no usas SignalR?

Comment: @AlfredoManuelCanReséndiz Es posible usarlo con un proyecto de API REST ??? Lo intenté pero me pareció que no se podía. Por eso estoy haciendolo así Básicamente lo que necesito es que cuando se haga un put o post que se envié una push notification con el cambio. Intente SignalR en primer lugar pero hay nula documentación de eso y la que hay es pero para applicaciones web no con webApi . Si usted tiene algún link sobre un ejemplo con webapi se lo agradezco.

Comment: No, creo que no leí completa tu publicación. Y si, en efecto no creo en un API REST no te va a funcionar SIgnalR, mas que nada porque utiliza Javascript en el cliente para estar en comunicación con el servidor, y si no me equivoco la idea de una API REST que sea independiente de la plataforma. Pero, la pregunta que hiciste también me sirve, ya que quisiera saber también como levantar un hub de notificaciones sin usar Azure. Así que, 1up a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

OK ya solucione el tema de la conexión.  Ahora el asunto es que no estoy recibiendo los mensajes. Para la conexión el problema se soluciono así:

```
 var cliente = new ClientWebSocket();

            WebSocketReceiveResult result;

            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

            var mensaje = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);

            await cliente.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://10.0.2.2:5000/ws"), CancellationToken.None);

            await Task.Run(async()=> {

                while (true)
                {

                  result= await cliente.ReceiveAsync(mensaje, CancellationToken.None);

                    var messageBytes = mensaje.Skip(mensaje.Offset).Take(result.Count).ToArray();

                    string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);

                }

            });
```

Despues de hacer la conexión se queda ahí y no pasa ni recibe los mensajes enviados en el ReceiveAsync, nisiquiera entra al while!!!

Comment: Esto parece ser una respuesta parcial, lo mejor es que sea una actualización a tu pregunta. Si no es así, y deseas hacer una pregunta aparte, puedes incluir un enlace a esta respuesta como referencia.